# Can setConnectionTimeout stop a download from completing

Tags: android, http, sockets, timeout

I am downloading a file in my app and using the following time-outs.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
```

Now and then the file is only partially downloaded. Can setSoTimeout of 5 seconds stop the download if it does not finish within 5 seconds on a slow mobile network?

From the Google Dev Docs it says:

> Sets the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds which is
>   the timeout for waiting for data.

Does this refer to the time to wait for first data, or the time to wait for any further data? IE the download starts but then no further data arrives for 5 seconds.

**EDIT**
I did a test where I reduced the SO_TIMEOUT to 100ms nad it had no effect in stopping the donwload from finishing only a second later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can setSoTimeout of 5 seconds stop the download if it does not finish within 5 seconds on a slow mobile network?

No, but it can throw a SocketTimeoutException if any particular read() call takes longer than 5 seconds to receive any data. What you do when you get that exception is up to you. You can retry.

If you're getting read timeouts, either the sender stalled, the network went down, or your read timeout is too short. 5000ms is a very short timeout. Raise it and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

Well as per documentation setting `SO_TIMEOUT` will raise `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` exception if the read call takes more time then specified (which in your case is 5000 milliseconds and this wait time refer to time from download starts), which means the exception will interrupt your downloading process.

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds.
>   With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the
>   InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this
>   amount of time. If the timeout expires, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still
>   valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking
>   operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero
>   is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if the file download does not complete in 5 seconds, the file download process will be halted? So I will have to increase this timeout to 10-20 seconds? Or is there a better way to handle the download?

Comment: Well setting SO_TIMEOUT to 0 means to wait infinitely, which to me should be the case here, as setConnectionTimeout is taking care of establishing connection or timing it out in due course.

Comment: I got this code from here on stackoverflow. Surely there must be a reason to also use SO_TIMEOUT? EDIT : I did some testing and changing SO_TIMEOUT to 100ms did nothing to stop the download from completing after a full second.

Comment: and the downloaded file was ok, i mean it wasn't corrupt or anything?

Comment: @Rynardt Misinformation here. It doesn't 'refer to the time from download starts'. It refers to the time each read() call is entered.